# Sugested edit was a rollback

Tags: discussion, editing

Not really a question.

I just reviewed and rejected this [suggested edit](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/18732). (I wasn't the only one so the edit is rejected.) But I zoomed in at the question, I saw [it was edited a few minutes before](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/35257/revisions). The suggested edit is a rollback of this edit although the comment suggest otherwise.

In this case, the original edit was an improvement so the rollback was not wanted. But my point is, that there is no way to detect a rollback in the suggested edit review tool. Not sure if we need it.

Comment: I think that was a manual edit to put in the old text as I don't think you have the ability to suggest a rollback of a post and that ability is only available for users with full edit privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that was an honest accident resulting from an edit collision, without being an attempt to roll back.

- [Revision 2](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/35257/revisions) was made by me at 09:34:27Z.
- That edit was submitted at 09:34:**33Z** — a mere six seconds later!

So we were both just editing the original version and submitted nearly simultaneously. The server did all it could.

> But my point is, that there is no way to detect a rollback in the suggested edit review tool. Not sure if we need it.

Probably not. A suggested edit that effectively proposes rolling back an improvement will usually face two problems:

- If it is removing genuine improvements, then the edit is actively making the post worse somehow.
- It is also likely to be making substantial changes of the type editors should not be attempting to make.

Either one of these would get the suggested edit rejected in the review queue.

If the pseudo-rollback actually improves the post and isn't a substantial change, the edit they're rolling back was probably pretty bad and they're doing us a favour.

Comment: Great, thanx that solves the mystery ;-).